# Can I manually feed the language code to Django gettext()?

Tags: python, django, localization

I have a few strings in the backend I'd need to occasionally translate to other language before using them. I plan to save the user language selection into the database so it would be easy to get it from there. But, what is unclear for me, is if I implement localization and have a couple of different language files, how can I use the right language version? I can't read the language selection from cookies, url, user session etc. Can I use the language code from my database to choose which translation I'll use?

Comment: `locale.set_locale` I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually activate the language with [activate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.activate). Here's an example, given the user has an language attribute with a valid language code:

```
from django.utils.translation import activate, deactivate
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

user = MyUserModel.objects.get(username=username)
activate(user.language)
my_string_translated_into_users_language = _("Hello")
deactivate()
```

That way, you override the current session language. Then deactivate() will deactivate the currently active translation object so that further _ calls will resolve against the default translation object, again.

Comment: This sounds really promising. So if I have two languages, en-us for English and da for Danish and English is the default language, I can use that activate to override the default language? Meaning I'll get the code da from the database and activate it.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood you. If you have implemented localization, as you write, then Django will handle this for you. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

Comment: I have a database field `language` under my User -model which contains just the language code, for example `da`. Then I of course have corresponding translations. Can I use `activate(user.language)` to use the Danish translation?

Comment: Yes. And if you want to make the language choice persist after the request lifecycle, you need to set `LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language